# Faster Algorithm to Tailor Given Mathematical Expression

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, math, mathematical-optimization

Is there a more optimized solution to solve the stated problem?

Given an array 'arr' of 'N' elements and a number 'M', find the least index 'z' at which the equation gets satisfied. [ ] is considered as floor().

[image]

**Code:**

```
counts=0
ans=0
while(ans==0):
    s=0
    for i in range(counts,len(arr)):
        s+=int(arr[i]/(i+1-counts))
        if(s>M):
            break
    if((i+1)==len(arr) and s<=M):
        print(counts)
        ans=1
    counts+=1
```

**Explanation:**

1. Check array from left to right. The first index that satisfies the condition is the answer. This is more optimized than considering from right to left.
2. If at any time during the calculation, 's' is deemed more than M, break the loop and consider the next. This is more optimized than calculating 's' completely.

**Example:**

**INPUT:**

N=3 M=3

arr=[1 2 3]

**OUTPUT:**

0

This would give the answer 0 since the 0th index contains the first element to satisfy the given relation.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you're working with relatively small arrays, your algorithm is going to be fast enough.  Minor improvements could be achieved by reorganizing the code a bit but nothing dramatic.

If you're working with very large arrays, then I would suggest you look into numpy.  It is optimized for array wide operations and has impressive performance.

For example, you can divide all the elements in an array by their inverted position in one operation:

```
terms = arr / np.arange(len(arr),0,-1)
```

and then get cumulative sums and the first index in a single line

```
index = np.where(np.cumsum(terms) <= M)
```

Comment: You're using the right tools, but you've solved a different problem to the one asked. Your solution assumes the last term is always the same, but it varies with z.

Comment: I wasn't trying to solve the problem but merely pointing out a toolset (numpy) that could be helpful to the OP and substantiating the suggestion with a few examples of the capacities of the tool.