# Improving the solution to Codejam's 'Infinite House of Pancakes'

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, time-complexity

I'm trying to solve the Codejam 2015's [Infinite House of Pancakes](https://code.google.com/codejam/contest/6224486/dashboard#s=p1) problem in the most efficient way. My current solution is similar to the one given in the [analysis](https://code.google.com/codejam/contest/6224486/dashboard#s=a&a=1) (but in Python instead of C++):

```
def solve():
    T = int(input())  # the number of test cases

    for case in range(1, T+1):
        input()  # the number of diners with non-empty plates, ignored
        diners = [int(x) for x in input().split()]

        minutes = max(diners)  # the max stack of pancakes (= the max time)

        # try to arrange all pancakes to stacks of equal height
        for ncakes in range(1, minutes):
            s = sum([(d - 1) // ncakes for d in diners if d > ncakes])  # number of special minutes
            if s + ncakes < minutes:
                minutes = s + ncakes

        print(f'Case #{case}: {minutes}')
```

The time complexity of this solution is `O(D*M)`, where `D` is the number of diners and `M` is the maximum number of pancakes.

However, the analysis also mentions another solution which is `O(D*sqrt(M) + M)`:

> Although the algorithm above is fast enough to
>   solve our problem, I have an even faster algorithm. Notice that the
>   list of ceil(a/1), ceil(a/2), ... only changes values at most
>   2*sqrt(a) times. For example, if a=10, the list is: 10, 5, 3, 3, 2, 2,
>   2, 2, 2, 1, 1, .... That list only changes value 4 times which is less
>   than 2 * sqrt(10)! Therefore, we can precompute when the list changes
>   value for every diner in only O(D*sqrt(M)). We can keep track these
>   value changes in a table. For example, if Pi=10, we can have a table
>   Ti: 10, -5, -2, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, .... Notice that the prefix
>   sum of this table is actually: 10, 5, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, .... More
>   importantly, this table is sparse, i.e. it has only O(sqrt(M))
>   non-zeroes. If we do vector addition on all Ti, we can get a table
>   where every entry at index x of the prefix sum contains sum of
>   ceil(Pi/x). Then, we can calculate sum of ceil(Pi/x)-1 in the code
>   above by subtracting the xth index of the prefix sum with the number
>   of diners. Hence, only another O(M) pass is needed to calculate
>   candidate answers, which gives us O(D*sqrt(M) + M) running time. A
>   much faster solution!

Can anyone give me a hint how to translate this to Python?

Comment: Take a look on the module `math`...

Comment: The same trick came up recently for a different problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54986763/2144669

Comment: @David: I can see some similarity, but I don't quite understand 1) what values should the table contain and how to use it.  2) How is precomputing it `O(D*sqrt(M))`.